# Enter the value in text box with JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that have a text box and beside of this text box I have some button that I want when user click on them some text go to the text box and submit the form.
For example I have this code:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="url"><br>
  <button type="button" value="www.example1.com">Website #1</button>
  <button type="button" value="www.example2.com">Website #2</button>
  <button type="button" value="www.example3.com">Website #2</button>
</form>
```

When user click on each of the button JavaScript automatically insert the value of the button then submit the form.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will you consider using jQuery?  if so rewrite it this way

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="txturl" name="url"><br>
<button type="button" value="www.example1.com" onclick="sendToSite('www.example1.com');">Website #1</button>
</form>

<script>


    function sendToSite(arg){
        $("#texturl").val(arg);
        $("#send.php").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Mark what you did is vandalism, do not do that again.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't get it. The original code does not work. There is no element with `texturl` id it is one with `txturl` instead and trying to query DOM elements by form action is not : `$('#send.php')`. Mark edit was fixing these issues.

Comment: @EmilCondrea that's not his place to edit code posted by others and change its meaning. The author of the code should do it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok. I thought that you wanted to tell him that the code improvement was not correct.

Comment: @EmilCondrea didn't even bother to look into it, I'm just against edits that radically change code posted by others.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the old code was not worked and I edit the code that work correctly, why you said that? you think it better a user see the code that not work or it's better when user see the code that work?!

Comment: @MarkLi that's not the point. It's not minor typo so you should leave a comment on the answer and let its author fix it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<form id="form1" action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="url" /><br>
    <button type="button" value="www.example1.com">Website #1</button>
    <button type="button" value="www.example2.com">Website #2</button>
    <button type="button" value="www.example3.com">Website #2</button>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
var url = document.getElementsByName("url")[0];
var buttons = form1.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++)
{
    buttons[index].addEventListener("click", function(){
        url.setAttribute("value", this.getAttribute("value"));
        form1.submit();
    });
}
```